# Determine string width in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I want to create a dynamic screen layout.

Is there a way to determine the  width for a string in a specific font?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_size()` to return the width and length of an element in pixels. For more information check the PySimpleGUI [documentation](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/call%20reference/#text-element).

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

my_string = 'Hello World!'

layout = [
    [sg.Text(text=my_string, key='-TEXT-', font=('Helvetica', 11))],
    [sg.Button('Go')]]

window = sg.Window(title='Name', layout=layout).finalize()

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == 'Go':
        # GETTING SIZE OF THE TEXT ELEMENT IN PIXELS
        size_of_text = window['-TEXT-'].get_size()   

        print('Width:', size_of_text[0], 'pixels')
        print('Height:', size_of_text[1], 'pixels')        

window.close()
```